# Replacing all new line charc in a file with a special character "#" in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

How to replace all "\n" occurrences in a text file with "#" using groovy in a jenkins pipeline

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried doing it outside of a pipeline, as a learning experience?

Comment: i tried few things with no luck    def fileText = concl.replaceAll("\n","\\|\\#\\|")
       concl.write(fileText)

Comment: concl.withWriter { w ->
            w << concl.text.replaceAll("\n","\\|\\#\\|")
          }

Comment: string t = readFileAsString(concl).trim().replaceAll("\n", "|#|")

Comment: i tried with sed on command line, it works but the same in groovy throws me strange errors with $ expression i have masked it with \$ and even used it in  " "  but no luck, so i decided to use the groovy inbuilt string replace operations instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work. Use the find operator ~ in Groovy

```
def parsedText = readFile("input.groovy").replaceAll(~/\n/, "#")
writeFile file: "output.groovy", text: parsedText
```

**EDIT**
If you use Declarative Pipeline Syntax, the working code is as follows:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('Print'){
            steps {
                script {
                    def inputText = readFile file: "1.groovy" 
                    inputText = inputText.replaceAll(~/\n/, "#")       
                    writeFile file: "2.groovy", text: inputText
                }
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ReadFileStep.file expects class java.lang.String but received class java.io.File

Comment: readFile takes File path(string) as an argument. Please accept this answer if it was helpful